# npm bin command - not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, npm, bin

i'm having problem with bin command. If I understand [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) correctly then after runing command from bin it should execute the file

So in my case `package.json` looks like:

```
  "author": "Andurit",
  "license": "contact author",
  "bin": {
    "shared-lib": "./node_modules/shared-lib-cli/bin/index.js"
  },
```

So I would expect that `shared-lib` in command line will execute `./path/bin/index.js`

Instead of that, I'm getting a command line **error**:

> shared-lib is not recognized as an internal or external command.

**What I want to use it for:**

`index.js` is some kind of parser which will build custom build of my library. You can imagine that as something similar as [lodash custom build](https://lodash.com/custom-builds)

So I usually use it like `node ./path/bin/index.js category=category1,category2`

**How I want it to work:**

```
shared-lib category=category1,category2
```

Guys, did I misunderstand the `bin` function and should I look for something else or does it ever happen to you that Windows (7 in my case) doesn't accept your bin command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey find out where is a problem, `npm install` should be runned globaly
e.g. `npm install -g`

I noticed I have in my package.json  `"preferGlobal": true,` however it looks it doesnt work as expected.